# How do i find the last letter inside a string, and get its index?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2015

Let's say I have a string called test,

```
string test = "hello my dear world"
```

and I want to get the last letter's index, (which is 19) .

How do I get that index, and insert it into an int/string?

Comment: `int index = test.Length;`

Comment: What should be returned for `"hello my dear world!!!"` or `"hello my dear world 123"`?

Comment: @S.Akbari : You should put `- 1` there too, as the index is zero-based.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *extremely* simple.

```
string test = "Hello World";
char theLastCharacterOfTest = test[test.Length - 1]; // 'd'
int theIndexOfTheLastCharacter = test.Length - 1; // 10
```

Want an explanation? Here it is!

Let's start with getting the index of the last character. Since C# uses a 0-based index system (i.e. the first index is 0), the last index is the length of the string - 1.

The last character is just the character at the last index, right? And the indexer of string returns the character at the index passed in. If we combine these two, we get `test[test.Length - 1]`.

I don't think you are very familiar with indexers, so here's a link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Comment: Your last line should also include the "-1"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you're looking for the *index* or *position* of the last character (you said the index is 19, but that's the position...the index is 18). Here's both:

```
string test = "hello my dear world";

// The length of the text gives the position of the last char
int position = test.Length;

// C# has a 0-based index. You need the string length -1 to get the last char's position
int index = test.Length - 1;
```

Here's [a working example](http://rextester.com/OOOT90700).

Comment: @HenkHolterman, What do you mean? Are you saying that a 0-based index is not universal in C#, or in programming in general?

Comment: No, it isn't. Not even in C#.

Comment: Can you give me an example where C# doesn't use a 0-based index? I'd like to understand what you're talking about :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = test.Length;
char LastLetter = test[index - 1];
```

please search , before posting your question.

Comment: test[index - 1] whats this mean

Comment: test is string in example , through string.[index] we can access to specific char in string  . so because in c# indexes starts from 0 so we must use [index-1]

Answer (score 0):

```
string test = "hello my dear world";

int index = test.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith("d"));
```

**OR**

```
int index = test.Length - 1;
```

Comment: Why did you put the -1?

Comment: its Sub string rule starting character find 0 and last character satart find in -1.